Recovering data from a disk that was formerly part of a RAID1 array
I read previous questions carefully and decided that mine is sufficiently different to justify a separate post. Apologies to anyone who is groaning inwardly.
For many years, I used a computer which was designed as a low-end server as my workstation. It had a SATA RAID1 array composed of two 120 GB Seagate Barracudas. When I decommissioned it five years ago, I removed the Seagates. They were working perfectly but are now bereft of their RAID controller, which is presumably in landfill somewhere in the home counties.
I now have occasion to access the data from the workstation in a read-only/RESCUE fashion. I bought a well-regarded USB--SATA/IDE converter kit and connected one of the two Seagates.
The drive powers up.
The drive is visible to Gparted (my first call) which identifies it as /dev/sdb
When I try to mount it using the command:
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/sata
...I get:
mount: /mnt/sata: unknown filesystem type 'silicon_medley_raid_member'.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
sudo fdisk -l gives:
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: XT-U33502
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
As I hope the query shows, I know something of how to handle disks in Linux... but former RAID disks are beyond my ken.
Can anyone give me a pointer? I believe that a process called a loop mount may be appropriate, but I couldn't figure out what's needed in order to read the contents of the disk.
I only need to read it once to transfer to archive. Don't need it to be a fully-working disk.
TIA, NP.

What exactly was the controller, and if hardware do you have one?  How was the array configured?  Two disks implies mirror, but not necessarily.

Hi John, I know they were mirrored because, uh, that's how I specced the machine when I bought it. I don't know what the controller was, it was trashed long ago -- and that's part of my problem. Some detective work since has revealed that the controller was one of the Silicon Medley systems and using that info I've been able to gain better access to the disks using the old PMRaid "fakeraid" utility, which has good support for Silicon's stuff... but I still can't mount them. Because of the slow start on this forum, I crossposted on TomsHardware and the datarecovery Reddit. NP

I was able to recover the data from my RAID disk today. Rather than printing DMDE outputs I thought it would be useful to take a step back and describe my entire process in case other visitors to the forum are dealing with a similar issue.
I used a Fairchild-branded server as my workstation for about a decade. It was a very good computer indeed, and its RAID array (two disks storing exactly the same data) gave it better data integrity than an off-the-shelf machine. When I decommissioned it five years ago, I removed the two RAID disks and disposed of the tower case.
This winter I needed to access the data from the disks. They're SATA drives with a standard hardware interface. I bought a $20 USB-SATA adapter on Ebay. I won't include a vendor URL for the device in question but it's basically a plastic box with a 12V power supply, a USB port and three SATA/IDE interfaces.
The box worked fine in that it powered up {whichever one of the pair of drives I connected to it} and that drive showed up in GParted when I hooked it up to my 2024 Linux workstation. However, the drives had been set up to work as part of a RAID array and wouldn't mount outside of that context. Thus I couldn't access my data.
A user on another forum prompted me to look at DMDE. It's available as freeware but the complexity of my archive -- 80000 files in 5000 directories -- obliged me to buy the $20/year "Express" membership. I'm very glad I did so, as DMDE was able to deal with the disk issue access in seconds. I had to get the files off as a "Recovery" operation, but they came across intact with their entire directory structure in place.
My expenditure on the recovery process was $40 and some time. That compares very favourably with commercial recovery operations and I'd recommend the route to anyone.
A RAID disk with media faults would be a different kettle of fish!
